# Saxon HE vs Saxon PE: File URI Resolution

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, saxon, exslt

My question is a very easy one. I just want to know if buying the professional version of Saxon will help with file URI resolution, since the professional version has the EXPath extension.

I'm asking this because no matter how hard I try, (passing command line parameters, using `file:///C|/path/to/text.csv`, etc.) Saxon-HE refuses to let my stylesheets load a raw text file using `unparsed-text('file:///C:/path/to/text.csv')`, and will only resolve the file if it comes from one of the network drives that are mounted, `unparsed-text('file://example.com/Dept/path/to/text.csv')`.

I have to ask this because the Saxon documentation explicitly states that `unparsed-text()` is [**NOT** dependant on any custom URI resolver classes being used](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/config-extend/uri-resolution/uri-resolver.html).

Comment: `unparsed-text('file:///C:/path/to/text.csv')` looks fine, you might want to tell us exactly which error you get, stating the exact version of Saxon HE you use, showing us how you call it, using the `-t` option from the command line for instance for detailed error diagnostics.

Comment: To be fair, Saxon doesn't give any errors: only the stylesheet will indicate when a CSV file couldn't be found. The stylesheet I'm using is [based on this example](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html), and I kept most of the stylesheet unchanged, aside from mapping what XML I needed in the template that generates the document.

Comment: So `unparsed-text-available()` gives false for your attempts. Are the URIs really as simple as `file:///C:/path/to/text.csv` or is there any white space in directory names?

Comment: There is no whitespace in the URIs to the CSVs. The URIs lead to  `C:\Bizvoice\text1.csv` and `C:\Bizvoice\text2.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your simple question is no. There are many benefits to the commercial Saxon editions but they aren't magic fairy dust: if you are using a URI that can't be dereferenced in Saxon-HE, then you need to work out what you are doing wrong rather than hoping that different software will work it out for you.

I would suggest trying it first on the simplest possible case. Create a file called `c:/test.txt`, and then try referencing it as `unparsed-text('file:///c:/test.txt')`. Come back to us and tell us whether that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, attempting to resolve a URI from `file:///c:test.txt` doesn't work. The only way the transformation occurs is when the path is resolved from a network drive. However: this may be because of how network drives have been set up; Our `%HOMESHARE%` variable is permanently linked to a network drive, as well.

Comment: @LeeS, `file:///c:test.txt` is wrong, it lacks a slash after the colon: `file:///c:/test.txt`.

Comment: That was a typo; sorry

Comment: The next thing I would try is to eliminate Saxon from the equation: try writing a little Java program that opens a URLConnection to file:///c:/test.txt. (Because that's all that Saxon is doing...)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to always check your raw text's encoding **BEFORE** you attempt to parse it in UTF-8 though XSLT. :^)